# JavaScript hide a corresponding field with specific delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the corresponding textarea field of a dropdown, It will be used in a lot of instance that's why I want it on a function.

```
<div id="formElement1" class="field">
    <label for="field1">Start and end date defined</label>
    <select id="field1" name="campaign-dd1">
      <option value="" >Please Select</option>
      <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
      <option value="No" >No</option>
      <option value="N/A" >N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement2" class="field">
    <label for="field2">Comment(s)</label>
    <textarea id="field2" name="campaign-comment1" ></textarea>
</div>
<div id="formElement3" class="field">
    <label for="field3">Content and workflow are compliant to requirements</label>
    <select id="field3" name="campaign-dd2">
      <option value="" >Please Select</option>
      <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
      <option value="No" >No</option>
      <option value="N/A" >N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement4" class="field">
    <label for="field4">Comment(s)</label>
    <textarea id="field4" name="campaign-comment2" ></textarea>
</div>
<div id="formElement5" class="field">
    <label for="field5">Flow working as planned</label>
    <select id="field5" name="campaign-dd3">
      <option value="" >Please Select</option>
      <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
      <option value="No" >No</option>
      <option value="N/A" >N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement6" class="field">
    <label for="field6">Comment(s)</label>
    <textarea id="field6" name="campaign-comment3" ></textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see in the code the dropdown `name=campaign-dd#` has a specific textarea `name=campaign-comment#`.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to show or hide the comment field?

Comment: On initial load. I want to hide it. And will display it once YES is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On initial load. I want to hide it. And will display it once YES is selected

In this case you can put a common class on all the `.field` elements which contains the comment fields, in my example below I used `.comment` and hide them in CSS. Then in JS you can put a `change` event handler on the `select` elements which shows/hides the related comment field based on the selected option. Try this:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.field').nextAll('.field:first').toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
});
```

```css
.field.comment {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formElement1" class="field">
  <label for="field1">Start and end date defined</label>
  <select id="field1" name="campaign-dd1">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement2" class="field comment">
  <label for="field2">Comment(s)</label>
  <textarea id="field2" name="campaign-comment1"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="formElement3" class="field">
  <label for="field3">Content and workflow are compliant to requirements</label>
  <select id="field3" name="campaign-dd2">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement4" class="field comment">
  <label for="field4">Comment(s)</label>
  <textarea id="field4" name="campaign-comment2"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="formElement5" class="field">
  <label for="field5">Flow working as planned</label>
  <select id="field5" name="campaign-dd3">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement6" class="field comment">
  <label for="field6">Comment(s)</label>
  <textarea id="field6" name="campaign-comment3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding classes that makes more sense would be easier, but you can construct the name for the textarea from the name given to the select, to hide it etc.

```js
$('.field select').on('change', function() {

    var parts = this.name.split('-');
    var numb = parts[1].replace(/\D/g, '');
    
    $('[name="' + parts[0] + '-comment' + numb + '"]').toggle(this.value !== 'Yes')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em>Select "Yes" to hide comment</em>
<br><br><br>
<div id="formElement1" class="field">
    <label for="field1">Start and end date defined</label>
    <select id="field1" name="campaign-dd1">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement2" class="field">
    <label for="field2">Comment(s)</label>
    <textarea id="field2" name="campaign-comment1"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="formElement3" class="field">
    <label for="field3">Content and workflow are compliant to requirements</label>
    <select id="field3" name="campaign-dd2">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement4" class="field">
    <label for="field4">Comment(s)</label>
    <textarea id="field4" name="campaign-comment2"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="formElement5" class="field">
    <label for="field5">Flow working as planned</label>
    <select id="field5" name="campaign-dd3">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="formElement6" class="field">
    <label for="field6">Comment(s)</label>
    <textarea id="field6" name="campaign-comment3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. I want to hide it on the initial load and be displayed once YES is selected.